# Display all phone contacts with a check box

Tags: java, android, android-widget

![I am developing an application in which I want to display all contacts with a checkbox, as shown in pic I can display all contacts but not with checkbox please help me.][1]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to display user's contacts in the ListView. In this case you have to create an adapter (most probably CursorAdapter) which you then connect to the ListView. For more information check out this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html